# acelerar por defecto aplicacion en C# con la grafica dedicada

Tags: c#, windows-forms, cefsharp

Tengo un desarrollo en C# y Winform para Windows el cual cuenta con un instalador `.msi`

Este desarrollo incluye un web container que implementa la librería `CefSharp`; el cual me gusta por su bajo consumo de memoria ram.

El problema es que por defecto todas las pagina que abro se ejecutan implementando la grafica dedicada; y yo quiero que por defecto si existe una grafica dedicada tire de esta para la aceleración por hardware.

1. Entre lo que investigue una solución es que el usuario, vaya y toquete el registro de uso de la GPU en el Sistema y cambien la opción a la de alto rendimiento:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Entonces esto realmente no me ayuda ya que dependo de que el usuario tenga que hacer configuraciones o cambio en su dispositivo, entonces tengo las siguientes dudas:

***Existe alguna forma en C# de obligar a que el programa tire de la grafica dedicada si existe para la ejecución de todos los procesos y subprocesos?***

mi programa inicia aquí:

```cs
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Xml;

namespace Web_Desktop
{
    public partial class Loader : Form
    {

        public VarManager varManager = new VarManager();

        public Common commonClass = new Common();

        public XmlManager xmlManager = new XmlManager();

        public WebSelector webSelector;

        public Loader()
        {

            InitializeComponent();

        }

        public void StartUp()
        {

            
            bool filecheck = File.Exists(varManager.configfile);

            if (!filecheck)
            {

                if (varManager.isAdministrator)
                {

                    xmlManager.CreateConfXML();

                }
                else
                {

                    commonClass.RestartApp(true);
                    
                }

            }
            else
            {

                bool checkRunAs = false;

                XmlNodeList admSetting = xmlManager.ReadRunAS();
                XmlNode nodoAdm = admSetting.Item(0);

                if (nodoAdm.InnerText == "true")
                {

                    checkRunAs = true;

                }

                if (checkRunAs && !varManager.isAdministrator)
                {

                    commonClass.RestartApp(true);

                }
                else
                {

                    webSelector = new WebSelector(this);

                    Thread.Sleep(1500);

                    webSelector.ShowDialog();

                }
                
                

            }

        }

        private void Loader_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Thread thread = new Thread(StartUp);

            thread.Start();
        }

        private void Loader_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
        {
            Application.Exit();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actualmente es posible acelerar una aplicación mediante código nativo en C# pero esto requiere mucho código y amplio conocimiento sobres la API de Intel, AMD y nvidia.

para este proyecto escogí usar otro método; en el cual se emplean los perfiles de configuración de Windows.

al iniciar la Aplicación podemos ejecutar este código:

```
        private static void SetPerformance()
        {

            string keyName = @"HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\DirectX\UserGpuPreferences\";
            string valueName = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;

            if (Registry.GetValue(keyName, valueName, null) == null)
            {

                var key = Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\DirectX\UserGpuPreferences");
                key.SetValue(valueName, "AutoHDREnable=1;GpuPreference=2;");

                string subProccess = Application.StartupPath + @"\CefSharp.BrowserSubprocess.exe";

                key.SetValue(subProccess, "AutoHDREnable=1;GpuPreference=2;");
                MessageBox.Show("The app will restart.");

            }
        }
```

el cual agregara al registro la aplicación que queremos acelerar.

Como adicional a esto estoy usando tambien `CefSharp`, he tenido que agregarlo tambien al Registro.