# Guardar registro en Windows

Tags: c#, refactoring

En esta [pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/543867/acelerar-por-defecto-aplicacion-en-c-con-la-grafica-dedicada) busco la forma de ejecutar una Aplicación con la Aceleración de la grafica dedicada de manera programática, pero después de un mundo de investigación, la forma más adecuada es apegándome a los perfiles de consumo y energía del sistema operativo.

Investigando sobre donde se controla o se maneja este dato, pude encontrar que lo puedo validar así:

```cs
string keyName = @"HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\DirectX\UserGpuPreferences\";
string valueName = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;
if (Registry.GetValue(keyName, valueName, null) == null)
{
    //Insertar el Registro
    //Solicitar reiniciar la Aplicación.

}
```

El problema es que no encuentro ejemplos o una explicación de como navegar entre los nodos del HKCU para llegar a insertar el valor si no existe:

Este ejemplo solo inserta en el nodo RUN:

```cs
string runKey = "SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run";
RegistryKey startupKey = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(runKey, true);
startupKey.SetValue("Arebokerts application", '"' + Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\arebokert.exe" + '"', Microsoft.Win32.RegistryValueKind.String);
```

**no se como adaptarlo.** con esto podría dar una respuesta a mi otra pregunta.

quiero lograr lo que esta en rojo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Existe dos formas de agregar los registros:

1. Agregando en el Instalador las instrucciones para que agregue los Registros del sistema.
2. Agregarlo mediante programación una vez se ejecute la aplicación.

no puedo implementar la #1 o no encontré como ya que el nombre de la clave a insertar es dinámica; lo he logrado con la opción #2:

```
        private static void SetPerformance()
        {

            string keyName = @"HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\DirectX\UserGpuPreferences\";
            string valueName = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;

            if (Registry.GetValue(keyName, valueName, null) == null)
            {

                var key = Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\DirectX\UserGpuPreferences");
                key.SetValue(valueName, "AutoHDREnable=1;GpuPreference=2;");
                MessageBox.Show("The app will restart.");

            }
        }
```

Paso a explicar el código:

1. Creamos la clave necesaria:

```cs
var key = Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\DirectX\UserGpuPreferences");
```

2. Guardamos el nombre del ejecutable como nombre de valor y el valor asignado:

```cs
key.SetValue(valueName, "AutoHDREnable=1;GpuPreference=2;");
```